# running through a loop and find a condition that match

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

I'm looking for an answer to this problem:
I'm running through a loop testing for a condition every time (if `data[i]` is red), and when a value of the array is red i print something but if the next value (`data[i+1]`) isn't red, i want to print something else to the rest of the line without testing if any next point is red or not. So my code was looking a little bit like this.

```
For i in range (0, 64) :
If data[i] = red :
Print '#'
If data[i+1] != red :
#here i want to print '.' for the rest of the line without testing anything and getting out of the loop
Else : 
print '#'
Else :
print '.'
```

And i don't know what to put to make this code work.

For example if in my array there is :
data[i] = red, data[i+1] = blank, data[i+2] = red. I want to remove second red. I want to print the rest of the array blank, without testing if it's red after a blank space.
I'm gonna use the algorithm in image processing. I've got two balls, one on the left and one on the right. This algorithm is gonna remove the one on the right entirely.

Comment: The question is quite interesting, but you found the worst way to ask it. make it python and format it properly.

Comment: I'm sorry i was on a mobile phone and i couldn't indent.

Comment: Try and find a real computer and tidy it up then. Also, what errors do you face?

Comment: It's not an error, it's just that i don't seems to know what algorithm to use. For example if there is a red point, after that a blank, after that a red point, i want to transform the second red point into a blank.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you want to achive. Please take five minutes, reformulate the question, add things like: what is the input data, what should be done, how should the output look like. Please also tidy up the python code.  Currently it contains a lot of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print `'#'` if `red` else print `'.'`. If encounted sequence `red`, not `red` then print `'.'` for the rest of the array:

```
prev = None
it = iter(data)
for point in it:
    if point == 'red':
       print '#',
    else:
       print '.',
       if prev == 'red': # encounted ['red', 'blank']
          break
    prev = point

for point in it:
    print '.',
print
```

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/E46gz)

```
blank blank red red blank red blank red red
. . # # . . . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this:

```
data = ['red','','', 'red','red','red','red','', 'red','red','','']

for i in xrange(len(data)):
    try:
        if data[i] == 'red' and data[i+1] == 'red':
            print '#',
        elif data[i] == 'red' and data[i+1] != 'red' :
            print '.',
    except IndexError:
        pass

ouput:
. # # # . # .
```

Comment: almost, it's if data[i] =='red' and data[i+1] != red, then from data[i+1] to the end i want to print '.' to the rest of the array without testing anything again.

Comment: @Tsunaze - so in the above example, what is your desired output?